# What is the difference between $f(\,\cdot\,,t)$ vs. $f(\,\cdot\,;t)$?

Tags: conventions, notation

What is the exact difference between $L(q,\dot{q}, t)$ and $L(q,\dot{q}; t)$, where $L$ is the Lagrangian for example?

I believe the latter to have a parametric dependence on $t$. Is that the case?

For example, let's consider the adiabatic expansion to time-dependent wavefuncton: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(\{\textbf{r}_i\}, \{\textbf{R}_I\}; t) & = & \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \Psi_l(\{\mathbf{r}_i \}; \{\mathbf{R}_I \}) \chi(\{\textbf{R}_I\}; t)
\end{eqnarray}
where, $\{\mathbf{r}_i\}$ and  $\{\mathbf{R}_i\}$ are the electronic  and nuclear degrees of freedom respectively in the case of a many-body problem. In this case, what do we mean with the kinds of time dependence the equation has?

Answer (score 3):

The choice of a semicolon $;$ instead of a comma as a separator between variables in a function is purely stylistic and it does not carry any specific and universal meaning. It is normally used to mark a shift in the kind of variables one is using. Ultimately, it is not necessary, but it can be useful in understanding the structure of the function at hand. The notation is somewhat similar, say, to $f_n(t)$: you need to put in an explicit numeric $n$ and $t$ to get a number back, so you could equally well write $f(n,t)$, but it's more helpful to write it as $f_n(t)$ because the structure is more immediately apparent.

As an example from pure mathematics, the [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) are often notated with two semicolons in the function call:
$$
{}_pF_q(a_1,\ldots,a_p ; b_1,\ldots,b_q; z) 
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n\cdots(a_p)_n}{(b_1)_n\cdots(b_q)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!},
$$
where the role and number of the $a_i$ is very different in character and function to that of the $b_j$.

Similarly, when it's used in a molecular wavefunction as, say, $\Psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3;\mathbf R_1,\mathbf R_2)$, the semicolon is there to indicate that the $\mathbf r_i$ and the $\mathbf R_j$ form two distinct groups of variables. I would tend to count a usage of the form $\Psi(\{\mathbf r_i\};\{\mathbf R_j\})$ as overly pedantic, to be honest, since the $\{\}$ already indicate that separation, but sometimes it's better if it follows an overarching notation scheme.

The same holds for the lagrangian call, $L(q,\dot q;t)$: here, $q$, $\dot q$ and $t$ can be any three real numbers you care to name, and $L$ will return a real number once you put them in, so an example in action could be
$$
L(q,\dot q;t) = \frac12 m \dot q^2 + \frac12 k(1+a\cos(\omega t))q^2.
$$
As always, the semicolon is not strictly necessary, but it helps emphasize the fact that $t$ is a different kind of variable from $q$ and $\dot q$ - the latter are dynamical variables, whereas time just parametrizes the evolution.

Comment: I kind of disagree with you when you say that $f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ can equally be written as $f\left ( n,x \right )$. From purely mathematical and/or computational point of view yes but I would say from physical point of view they can be completely different. I would never try to plot  $f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ in 3D while I would definitely do so for  $f\left ( n,x \right )$.

Comment: @linuxick $f_n(x)$ denotes a function $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ (or similar), and the notation $f(n,x)$ is entirely appropriate. Plotting 'slices' in 3D may or may not be a good idea, but if you cannot see the notation $f(n,x)$ without compulsively making 3D plots of it, then that's on you. In any case, though, that's exactly the point - it *can* be written that way, but that doesn't mean that it *should* be.

Answer (score 0):

I think physics should be understood at the very basic levels, with languages as easy and understandable as possible. Let me put up some points here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Consider the following integration:

$$g(t) = \int_{x_1(t)}^{x_2(t)} f(x;t)dx$$
where, the dependence of $t$ is parametric. $f(x;t)$ in this case, is say, 
$$f(x;t) = ax+bt$$
Thus, we can safely write $f(x;t)=f(x,t)$. I think, it is better to write $f(x,t)=ax+bt$ outside the integration, i.e., when we are not carrying out integration (or other operations of similar kinds) on it. But when we use it for operation on $x$ (such as integration here), to distinguish the fact that the integration is over $x$, not over $t$, we might introduce "$;$", instead of "$,$" as separator.

Carrying the same logic for the case of the many body wave function, cannot we argue as follows ?

$$
\Phi(\{\textbf{r}_i\}, \{\textbf{R}_I\}; t)  =  \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \Psi_l(\{\mathbf{r}_i \}; \{\mathbf{R}_I \}) \chi(\{\{\textbf{R}_I\}; t)
$$
For $\Phi(\{\textbf{r}_i\}, \{\textbf{R}_I\}; t)$, operations (eg, integration) would be carried out over $\{\textbf{r}_i\}$ and  $\{\textbf{R}_I\}$ and not over $t$.

For $\Psi_l(\{\textbf{r}_i\}; \{\textbf{R}_I\})$, operations (eg, integration) would be carried out over $\{\textbf{r}_i\}$ and not over $\{\textbf{R}_I\}$.

For $\chi(\{\textbf{R}_I\};t)$, operations (eg, integration) would be carried out over $\{\textbf{R}_I\}$ and not over $t$.

Comment: Not fully, no. As a simple example, you do care about $i\hbar\partial_t$ acting on $\Phi$ and $\chi$, and you do care about the $\mathbf R$ derivatives of the $\Psi_l$. The semicolon is purely a notational device to be used where it helps structure things better, but there are no hard-and-fast rules of what it means - it's just used to denote a difference in kind in the variables of a function.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, this notation is usually reversed for telling the difference between a variable and a parameter. For example, define force as 
$F(a;m)=ma$ vs $F(a,m)=ma$. The first would be seen as a single variable function, with a fixed parameter m. Where the second would be seen as a multivariable function, where m may not be necc. fixed.

If you look at asymptotic theory, or perturbation there, you would see the notation $f(x;\epsilon)$. Where $\epsilon$ is a small, fixed parameter.

Answer (score -1):

In the Lagrangian approach the action is a function of a path $\gamma$ on the configuration space $TQ$ (viewed as tangent bundle over some base manifold $Q$). The configuration space is itself a manifold and can be locally described by the set of variables $(q,v)$ (with all the more or less complicated charts transformations): the path $\gamma$ can, instead, by parametrised by making use of a real paramenter $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

In terms of the coordinates living on the configuration space, the path $\gamma$ can be then described as collection of points $(q(t), v(t))$ at any allowed value of $t$: **on the solutions of the Lagrangian equations of motion** (and only there) one has that $\dot{q}(t) = v(t)$.

In a nutshell: $t$ specifies the flow parameter, $(q,v)$ specify the manifold charts. Some authors want to (rightfully) keep the difference in the notations as $f(q,v;t)$.

Comment: I completely disagree. The notation $f(q,v;t)$ does *not* mean that $f$ depends on $t$ through the time-dependence of $q$ and $v$; instead, it implies that $f$ is defined for arbitrary $q$ and $v$ but that, even if you're only looking at curves $q=q(t)$ and $v=v(t)$, $f$ has (or can in principle have) an explicit dependence on $t$.

Comment: ...which is exactly what I said: where have I stated that f *"depends on t through the time-dependence of $q,v$"*?

Comment: That's pretty much how your answer reads - if that's not what you intended, I'd recommend you step back a bit and see it with fresh eyes. Saying "$t$ specifies the flow parameter" is either wrong or completely misleading: the notation $f(q,v;t)$ does *not* imply *any* relationship between $q$ and $t$, and it does *not* presuppose any specific path $\gamma$ on $TQ$. Why you're talking about that is beyond me.

Comment: (Ditto for why you're talking about the solutions of the Lagrangian equations of motion. $L(q,\dot q;t)$ is defined for any arbitrary triplet $(q,\dot q,t)$, as opposed to what your second paragraph implies.)

Comment: I do not understand your remarks (however my intend is to mean what you re-phrased in your first comment): how is *"$t$ specifies the flow parameter"* wrong? In the Lagrangian approach it does indeed, and the Lagrangian description is by definition meant to resolve the path $\gamma$ such that $S[\gamma]$ has an extremum. That then we want to take any other function $f$ and introduce or describe the notation, this is another matter and in another context such notation might mean something different.

Comment: As for your last comment *"L is defined for any arbitrary triplet $(q,\dot{q},t)$, as opposed to what your second paragraph implies"* this is incorrect, as the Lagrangian is *only* defined for arbitrary $(q,v)$: if you are outside the solution of the equations of motion, it is not necessarily true that $\dot{q}$ serves to describe the configuration space at all.

Comment: The equations of motion are completely irrelevant as to whether $\dot q$ is actually the velocity of some possible path through $TQ$ - that's precisely the point of lagrangian mechanics. In any case, your answer implies that $L$ is a function $TQ\to \mathbb R$, which is precisely what the notation $L(q,v;t)$ specifies need not be the case - instead, it's a function $L:TQ\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, with an additional and arbitrary time dependence through the third argument. The only thing that stops this answer from being more wrong is how muddled and unclear it is.

Comment: *"...In any case, your answer implies that L is a function $TQ\to\mathbb{R}$"* I honestly don't see anywhere in the text where this is implied, I don't understand why you're assuming this is what is meant when it isn't, all in all. Also, it seems again you have misread my remark on the issue $\dot{q}$ vs $v$: I am however unable to re-phrase it any better than what I have already done.